# positive look behind match until newline or start of string

Tags: php, regex

I need to match a datestamp and then look behind until start of string or new line

## pattern

```
$date_day_pattern = '(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])';
$date_month_pattern = '(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])';
$date_year_pattern = '(?:[12][0-9]|20[12][0-9])';

$prefix_pattern = '(?<=[^\n]*)';
$date_pattern = "(?<!\d|\d )($date_day_pattern)[^\d\n]?($date_month_pattern)[^\d\n]?($date_year_pattern)(?!\d)";

preg_match("/$prefix_pattern$date_pattern/", $input, $matches);
```

## input

```
dksj dkk
49.. dk /ak 01-05-2012 hey
kdks
```

## match

\\1 `49.. dk /ak`

\\2 `01`

\\3 `05`

\\4 `2012`

Comment: Something like [`^([^\nb]*)(b)`](https://regex101.com/r/zM5sR3/1)? Could you please precise the requirements? Lookbehinds do not consume the text, though you can capture substrings with them.

Comment: the match pattern is more complex than just maching `b` so your solution would not work

Comment: You can simply use `r'(.*)b'` the frist group would be the string before `b` until new-line, or just use `^(.*)b` with multi-line flag. You even don't need the second group be the `b` character when you know it already.

Comment: Have you tried: `preg_match('/^(.*)'.$date_pattern.'/m', $input, $matches);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that you think adding a lookbehind you can capture the beginning of the line before the date your main `$date_pattern` matches.

It is not possible to use a lookbehind of unknown width in PCRE regex.

Instead, you may *capture* all the text from the beginning of the line (`^` with the MULTILINE modifier) up to the first date with lazy dot matching.

Here are two line changed that do the trick:

```
$prefix_pattern = '^(.*?)\s*';
...
preg_match("/$prefix_pattern$date_pattern/m", $input, $matches);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/NNiT3j)

This way, the `$prefix_pattern` is equal to `^(.*?)\s*` matching the start of line (as `/m` is added to the `preg_match` pattern), 0+ chars other than a newline, as few as possible (`.*?`), are captured into Group 1, and 0+ whitespaces are matched outside that group with `\s*`.

You may further tweak group number/boundaries to adjust the resulting array of captured values.